# How to make CAEmitterCell fade-in and then fade-out?

Tags: ios, caemitterlayer, caemittercell

I am using CAEmitterLayer to emit some star images. Our clients want to change the alpha of the star from 0 to 1 , and then to 0. I know we can use alphaSpeed property of CAEmitterCell to increase or decrease the alpha, but how to change the alpha like 0 -> 1 -> 0 ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can animate any emitter cell property using key value coding. See http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_emitter_layers

Comment: Thanks! But this solution did not help.
I've read the article and tried the code below:  //////////////     

 let baseAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "emitterCells.star.alphaSpeed")
        baseAnimation.fromValue = 0.3
        baseAnimation.toValue = -0.3
        baseAnimation.duration = 3
        baseAnimation.repeatCount = 1000;
        particleEmitterLeft.add(baseAnimation, forKey:"")

/////////////////As the animation is add to the layer, the alpha property of all the stars will be changed together. This is not what I need.

Comment: I was not suggesting you should animate a change in the alpha speed.